# ASP.NET Core 7 with multiple Angular instances

Tags: angular, localization, asp.net-core-7.0

I try to run under one ASP.NET Core 7 application with multiple localized Angular apps.

Currently I use the default ASP.NET Core web application template with `--localize` switch on Angular compile. This results in two Angular folders:

```
ClientApp/dist/en
ClientApp/dist/de
```

I tried to configure the mapping like this:

```
...
app.Map("/de",
    userApp =>
    {
        userApp.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/dist/de";
            spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                                                       {
                                                           FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp", "dist", "de"))
                                                       };

            // if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            //     spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4000");
        });
    });
app.Map("/en",
    userApp =>
    {
        userApp.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/dist/en";
            spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                                                       {
                                                           FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp", "dist", "en"))
                                                       };
        });
    });

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

But when I request `localhost:80/de`, I get an error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint: 'Fallback {*path:nonfile}'. Please register the EndpointMiddleware using 'IApplicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(...)' if using routing.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.<>c.b__18_0(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__1(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context, PathString matchedPath, PathString remainingPath)

This solution worked under ASP.NET Core 5, but and the most examples I can find are way older.

Comment: No real. Currently I run each localized ui under a own port and map everything together via proxy server. It works but is very urgly.

Comment: try to specify default page for each locale: `spa.Options.DefaultPage = new PathString("/index.html")`

Comment: Thousand thanks, kemsky. Your message pointed me to the right direction. I post the solution in a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it now to work, with these changes:

First I dropped `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");` and moved it into the mappings like that `spa.Options.DefaultPage = new PathString("/en/index.html");`.

Second I had to add `userApp.UseSpaStaticFiles(...)`.

And here the complete code:

```
app.Map("/de",
    userApp =>
    {
        userApp.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                                  {
                                      FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "de"))
                                  });
        userApp.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.DefaultPage = new PathString("/de/index.html");

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4000");
        });
    });
app.Map("/en",
    userApp =>
    {
        userApp.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                                  {
                                      FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "en"))
                                  });
        userApp.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.DefaultPage = new PathString("/en/index.html");

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4001");
        });
    });

app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.Use((Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task>)((context, _) =>
                                                            {
                                                                context.Response.Redirect("/de");
                                                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                                                            }));
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly! Only thing I did different was executing this block when `!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()`, in this case I use the default `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html")` command. That's 50 reputation well spent.